# How to add more items to the list without going to the next row?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My list can fit up to 6 items, and it's laid out like this:

[image]

Now, I want to make it fit more than 6, but I don't want to display the extra one on the new row either.

Simple Logic: If there are 6 or more item, create them to right of the list and show the big `>` so that the users will know that there is more.

How do I do that? Can I use the CSS Carousel to get this done? Will I need JS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at the `overflow` property in Css.
If it is set to scroll the content is clipped if you provide the proper width.
An example css is shown below

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Good luck!